# iPhone Alternate View for Landscape Mode on Rotation

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I'm looking to have an alternate view for one of my ViewControllers when the user rotates the device to landscape (think CoverFlow in iPod) I have implemented this using the *AlternateViews* sample code (listening for a device rotation notification).

However, I've noticed a bug. I have a rather complicated UI - TabViewController/UINavigationController. When on one ViewController that uses the *AlternateViews* code and switch to another tab that also has an *AlternateView* the notifications seem to compete. Meaning it will show the *AlternateView*, but the one for the first tab's view controller not the second. If I *back* out of the navigation hierarchy so only one AlternateView exists, then it's fine.

In the end, I don't need an entirely separate ViewController for landscape mode. In fact, this is actually making things more complicated as I need it to have the same navigation bar and `IBActions`. What I need is to load in a UIWebView on device rotation (if not already loaded) and hide the current view (UITableView). This would also alleviate the bug above.

I can setup the code to create/show/hide the UIWebView and UITableView. However, I don't know exactly where or when to do that - `willAutoRotateToOrientation`? Any reference to the delegate method and psuedo code would be greatly appreciated.

Of course, if anyone has a *fix* for the *AlternateViews* sample code, given my UI hierarchy, I would appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting your code that swaps out the views into -didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

That way, your existing view starts to visibly rotate, then the new view gets swapped in and completes the rotation.

Comment: I have implemented this, doing exactly what the poster described.  It works really well.